# mongodb aggregation, is it possible to add entries to an array during $project

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents of the form:

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(.....),
    prop1 : "foo",
    links : [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
}

{
    _id : ObjectId(.....),
    prop1 : "bar",
    links : [ 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
}
```

I am using the aggregation framework to process these documents, I use $unwind to generate a document for each value in the links array.

But I have three cases where I need to update the documents before calling $unwind, I have been looking at the $project operation, but I can find no information about how to create or update arrays for the following cases.

1) The links property is missing

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(.....),
    prop1 : "far"
}
```

I need to insert the links array

2) The links array property is an empty array

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(.....),
    prop1 : "far",
    links : []
}
```

I need to insert a value into the array

3) The links array has too few values

```
{
    _id : ObjectId(.....),
    prop1 : "far",
    links : [ 9, 10 ]
}
```

I need to insert additional values into the array

Comment: I'd look at `$cond` to conditionally add the values: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/

Comment: I am familiar with $cond, The problem I have is that I can't figure out how to actually create arrays or update array values. I just updated the question to better reflect this.

Comment: You can't actually modify the documents permanently. It would only be during the pipeline that you could modify a field's value.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want, I want to modify them for the scope of the aggregation pipeline only. The values are query dependent so can't be persisted to the documents in the DB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use `$isNull` ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#exp._S_ifNull)):

```
db.test.aggregate({ $project : { the_links: { $ifNull : ["$links" , [5,6]]}} })
```

It's simple logic that if the referenced field (`$links`) is null, the replacement value (in this case `[5, 6]`) is used. I renamed the field to `the_links` in the example.

Assuming the `links` field is null (and not an empty array). Given data like:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "prop1" : "foo", "links" : [  1,  2,  3,  4 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId(...), "prop1" : "bar" }
```

The aggregation above produces:

```
{
    "result" : [
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("52a869d51d02442354276cff"),
                    "the_links" : [
                            1,
                            2,
                            3,
                            4
                    ]
            },
            {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("52a869e31d02442354276d00"),
                    "the_links" : [
                            5,
                            6
                    ]
            }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If links were an empty array `[]` rather than `null`, you could do something like:

```
db.test.aggregate({ $project : 
     { the_links: { $cond : [ { $eq : ["$links", []]}, '$links', [5,6]]}} })
```

But, if it's either null or `[]`, then you'd need to add an additional check for that condition as an `$or` within the `$cond` operator.

If the list has values, and you want to add more values conditionally, the current (2.4.x) production build of MongoDB does not have an effective solution. The development branch has an operator called `$size` which will return the length of an array ([jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4899)). You could then conditionally add them using yet another development feature called $setUnion:

> **$setUnion**
>   Takes any number of arrays and returns an array that
>   containing the elements that appear in any input array.

Comment: That looks like it will work for cases 1 and 2, do have any thoughts on case 3, where I need to add values to an existing array. I have been looking at the changes for mongo 2.6 and there is a $map function that can be applied to each entry in an array but it does not look like it will let me insert values into the array.

Comment: actually just seen the new set operators in 2.6, $setUnion will take any number of arrays and generate the union of them. I might be able to use $project to add the new values into a new array property and then $setUnion to merge them, or maybe even use a literal array as one of the values. I'll have to download 2.6 and give it a try.

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do? Why are you trying to add values to the array? I added a few details about future version support.

Comment: I think maybe you have the parameters of the `$cond` operator in the wrong order. From documentation: `{ $cond: [ <boolean-expression>, <true-case>, <false-case> ] }`  So in your example, it will keep the empty array, or replace an non-empty array with the hard coded one...

Comment: @Vegar - It's a two year old question, and from the looks of it, I would have said that I actually used the MongoDB console to test and produce the output you see in the answer.

Comment: Yes, i did notice the age. Anyway, i had to flip the cases around before it worked today - but then it worked, so either they changed the order in the last two years or something else is going on....